# How do I turn this tuple that holds every single word and how many times its repeated across?

Tags: python

So, the code is effectively almost done, I just have to solve this quality of life problem: Converting this tuple to a string.

What my code is supposed to do is take the text from 5 websites of my choice and count the top 15 words. I succeeded, but the output is too ugly.

It's a tuple of everything, but I need a string with only the top 15.

How can I turn this tuple which has counted and been sorted into a string and only print the top 15 words?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from urllib2 import *
from collections import Counter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from re import split
import string
import sys



def url_to_text(url, fp):
        file= urlopen(url)
        str_html = file.read()
        obj_html = BeautifulSoup(str_html, "html.parser")
        for element in obj_html(["script", "style"]):
                element.extract()
        str_text = obj_html.get_text()
        #Clean the text
        for char in '[]/:0123456789""()-.,\\n':
                str_text = str_text.replace(char, ' ')
        str_text = str_text.lower()
        word_list = str_text.split()
    count_unique(word_list)
        fp.write(str_text.encode('utf-8'))

def count_unique(chunk):
        d = {}
        word_freq = []
        for word in chunk:
                d[word] = d.get(word, 0) + 1
        for key, value in d.items():
                word_freq.append((value,key))
        word_freq.sort(reverse=True)
        convertTuple(word_freq)
        print(word_freq)

def convertTuple(tup):
        str_join = "\n".join(str(tup) for x in tup)
        return str_join

fp=open("tmp.txt", "w+")
url_to_text("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA", fp)
url_to_text("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AB", fp)
url_to_text("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC", fp)
url_to_text("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZY", fp)
url_to_text("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZZ", fp)
```

Comment: Can you please share the output you are getting and the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Use a list slice to just get the top 15:

```
print(convertTuple(word_freq[0:15]))
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your tuple is named results

```
top15 = str(results[:15])
```

You should think about using pandas dataframe to make a nice table overview.

Answer (score 0):

Python provides Collections module for this purpose.

`from collections import Counter`

in url_to_text function

```
    word_list = str_text.split()
    words=Counter(word_list).most_common(15)
    top_words=list(map(lambda x:x[0],top_words))
```

you will get list of top 15 words.